# Connect 4 Matrix Orientation

Tags: graphics, game-development, brython, connect-four

I'm making a Connect 4 game for my Performance Task for AP CSP and I cannot get the grid to print in the right orientation. It seems like the board is being rotated right and then mirrored/flipped. Note: This is written in Brython on CodeHS.

```
def game():
    matrix2 = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
    #column 1 is (0,0)(1,0)(2,0)etc
    print("(2,0) (row,column) : " + str(matrix2[2][0]))
    #Outline of the board
    #rectangle(get_width()-30, get_height()-30,(get_width()/2-rect.get_width()/2), (get_height()/2-rect.get_height()/2), '#274ecf' )
    rect = Rectangle(get_width()-30, get_height()-30)  
    rect.set_position((get_width()/2-rect.get_width()/2), (get_height()/2-rect.get_height()/2))
    rect.set_color('#274ecf')
    add(rect)
    #Board
    rect = Rectangle(get_width()-50, get_height()-50) 
    rect.set_position((get_width()/2-rect.get_width()/2), (get_height()/2-rect.get_height()/2))
    rect.set_color('#2b56e3')
    add(rect)
    #matrix x/90-70 y/90-70 
    #Slots
    
    def slot(x,y):
        circle = Circle(40)
        circle.set_position(x,y)
        if matrix2[x//90][y//90]==0:
            print(matrix2[x//90][y//90])
            circle.set_color(Color.white)
            add(circle)
        elif matrix2[x//90][y//90]%2==0:
            circle.set_color(Color.yellow)
            add(circle)
        else:
            circle.set_color(Color.red)
            add(circle)
            
    def row():
        x=70
        for i in range(6):
            x+=90
            a=70
            for i in range(7):
                slot(x,a)
                a+=90
    row()
```

This is what it looks like it looks like when ran:[picture of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVETM.png)

I tried switching x and y and I also try rearanging the nested for loops under the function "row". Any advice helps! Thank you!